# Sharing data between controllers in Typescript | Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have worked with angular js with javascript where as I  know I can able to create service to share data . I am new to typescript it would be great if anyone  could help us to understand how to create service in  typescript to share data between controllers

The below sample service is called from the controller. Even I changed the service values when I tried redirect from other page the value is not getting changed it is having the default values. Though I am using the syntax

```
angular.module("app").service(...)
```

I believe the service is creating new instance when the controller is loaded.

```
 export class sharedData {
        public getMyProperty(): boolean {
            return this._myProperty;
        }
        public setMyProperty(value) {
            this._myProperty= value;
        }
        private _myProperty: boolean = false;
    }

angular.module("app")
    .service("sharedData", App.RfiDetail.sharedData);
```

I have tried with function also , but its not working

```
export function sharedFactory() {


    return {
        setStatus: setStatus,
        getSuccess: getSuccess
    };

    function setStatus(value) {
        this._myProperty = value;
    }

    function getSuccess() {
        return this._myProperty;
    }
}
angular.module(App.Constants.Modules.app)
    .factory("sharedFactory", App.RfiDetail.sharedFactory);
```

Comment: service should be a function, why you're trying to do it with class?.. TS is just a super set of javascript, you can use the same function as before.